# Ext JS - best way to bind Panel to data Store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to Ext JS and have noticed two ways in which a grid / tree can bind to a data source (Store):

1. `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('someStoreId');`
2. `Ext.getStore('someStoreId');`

Is Ext.getStore just some shorthand for StoreManager.lookup? Is there a performance difference between the two or would it be considered best practice to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are the same thing, it doesn't matter which one you call, `getStore` is for typing convenience and [it calls `StoreManager`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/StoreManager.html#Ext-method-getStore).

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore

> Shortcut to Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup.

And they are both horrible ideas. You are basically creating global variables. You should prefer passing references to stores you create instead.

Take their [grid example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel):

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

It can be rewritten so that the store is not globally reachable, since the store manager is a global singleton.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: store,
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the tip about passing a reference variable as an alternative

Comment: The store is still globally reachable via StoreManager and there is no way to avoid the store being available via StoreManager - just you aren't using that global visibility. A store with a storeId is always registered with StoreManager; and I think stores without explicit store Id get an auto-generated storeId  before registering. To be honest, I think both the store manager and the local scope have their use cases. The usual way of binding a store to a grid in an application is `store:'myStore'`, which is using `StoreManager.lookup` under the hood, by the way.

Comment: @Alexander I meant to remove the `storeId` from the declaration, fixed. And yes they may have their use cases, but a global has to really be if you have no other way out... It just bothers me that Ext uses it in simple examples where they are not necessary

Comment: Maybe it bothers you - I for myself like the additional possibility to debug complex issues from browser console by calling the StoreManager.

Comment: @Alexander Then you may as well expose all your private variables to make it easier to debug?

Comment: Not all of them, but most are exposed by default because at some point they are part of an object or function that is somewhere in the object tree.